# trying to create a simple plugin with ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have created plugins before but i must be missing something simple. 
I have gone back to the tutorial and trying to add a very simple plugin. code below:

I do not get an error on the console and i do not see the icon in the editor

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**In my PHP i have**

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
    {
    toolbar : 'MyToolbar',
    customConfig : '/admin/ckeditor/my_config.js?v=5.1',
    height : '400px',
    });
```

my_config.js looks like ::
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){
        config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
        fullPage : true;
        extraPlugins : 'pdf';

```
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
    config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
[
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About','Pdf' ] }
];    

};
```

**and the dir structure in the plugins dir is:**

ckeditor

-->plugins

------>pdf

--------->images

------------>pdf.png

--------->plugin.js

**and plugin.js looks like:**

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'pdf', 
{
init: function( editor )
{
    editor.addCommand( 'insertPdf',
        {
            exec : function( editor )
            {    
                var timestamp = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: <em>' + timestamp.toString() + '</em>' );
            }
        });
    editor.ui.addButton( 'Pdf',
    {
        label: 'Insert PDF',
        command: 'insertPdf',
        icon: this.path + 'images/pdf.png'
    } );
}
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.
in the my_config.js i had

```
extraPlugins : 'pdf';
```

instead of

```
config.extraPlugins = 'pdfs';
```